# Efficient way to know Actual caller

Tags: c++11

There are two API **requestSession**() and **releaseSession**()
Both call response will be received on **OnSessionChanges**. Can one suggest an Efficient way to know either response is for **requestSession** or **releaseSession**.

This is asynchronous call and there is the changes that Even **requestSession()** is called first but **releaseSession()** response may  come early than **requestSession()**.

```
enum session
{

 R_SUCCESS
 R_FAIL
 R_RELEASED
 R_NO_RESPONSE
};

    API Request
    1.requestSession(ID)
    2.releaseSession(ID)

    OnSessionChanges(const session& sess_)
    {

    }
```

Comment: This does not seems like standard C++ so you should indicate what library you are using or provide appropriate code.

Comment: Please create a compilable example, your problem seems to make sense, but your example code do not!